# How To Check For Directory On A Give Argument

Tags: unix, scripting

If the argument is 0 then script should check directory called “App0” is in the windows path variable. If not exists, then add \App0 in the path. I Am Struggling To Understand ( If the argument is 0 ).

My Work So Far.

```
if [ -d "${Appo}" ]; then
    echo "Appo Doesn't Exist."    
    mkdir Appo
    echo "File Created"
fi
```

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean when you say "path variable"? Do you mean [the PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))? If so, why is your code creating a directory when what you need is to change the value of the PATH variable? Also: your question is tagged with unix, but you are asking about Windows. Are you using an emulation of a unix-like environment running on Windows? Which one?

Comment: I Am MySelf Confused About The Question. if argument is 0 check directory in windows (path variable). i don't understand it myself i was asked by a teachers. This Is What He Replied.                                                                         If the argument is 0 then you have to check the directory App0 is in the PATH. If you type echo %PATH% then it will tell your current path.

Comment: unless you can indicate why you removed the unix tag it should be left in there. the scritping tag is a generic tag which can cover Unix, Windows and PHP Command Line scripts which would have different answers

Comment: I Haven't Removes The tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $# == 0 ]]
then
    echo "zero args"
fi

for arg in "$@"   # You might get more than one argument.
do
    dir="App${arg}"   # Make the name by combining the strings.
    if [[ -d $dir ]] 
    then
        echo "App$arg exists"
    else
        mkdir "$dir"  # Be careful the name supplied may contain spaces.
        echo "Created directory: $dir"
    fi
done
```

Comment: If the argument is missing, program should call the function – “ERROR1” which print the error and exit. How Can I Do This.???